# retrieving values in one row of dataframes based on value in other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have mutiple DataFrames, each containing a row called 'location' and another row called 'value' (both make up the index). for example, suppose i have the following 2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[-4,2,5],['nyc','sf','chi']]), columns=['col1','col2','col3'], index=['value','location'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[5,0,-3],['nyc','sf','chi']]), columns=['col1','col2','col3'], index=['value','location'])
```

the DataFrames will be housed in a dictionary that I can iterate through. Ultimately, I want to retrieve the list of 'value's for each 'location' in a separate DataFrame. so the desired output would look like:

[image]

this is a toy example, while my real one will have many more DataFrames and the source DataFrames will have other rows besides the 2 key ones I am interested in

Comment: Do all data frames have the same values for the "location" row?

Comment: yes, the number and values of the "location" row are the same in all dataframes, however i should mention that the column placement might not be. e.g. nyc could be under col1 in one dataframe but under col2 in another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `set_index` and `concat`:

```
(pd.concat([df.T.set_index('location')['value'] for df in [df1, df2]], axis=1)
   .T
   .reset_index(drop=True))

location nyc sf chi
0         -4  2   5
1          5  0  -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge`

```
df1.T.merge(df2.T,on='location').set_index('location').T
location nyc sf chi
value_x   -4  2   5
value_y    5  0  -3
```